# Hvac condensate line not draining, New ac system

Tags: hvac, condensate

Hi so I just purchased a house. It was a bank foreclosure. The bank installed a new ac unit. The ac wasn't running in day one. I figured out it was bc the condensate line wasn't draining properly. The drain pan was full and the wet switch was causing the power to be cut. I vacuumed that up and the ac works now. The problem is that the condensate still isn't draining properly. I the pipe is not clogged. I put some downward pressure on at as shown here

And I could here the water draining into the sump pump.

I took as many pictures as possible. Is this something I could perhaps fix myself or should I just call an hvac service?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/01A7Q.jpg

Sorry for the poor formatting, trying to do all this from my phone.

Comment: Do you have enough pitch in pipe to drain? If not need a pump to help.

Comment: So what I'm noticing is that the pipe coming out of the hvac is angled upwards and I believe that it the crux of it

Comment: Yeah, water only flows downhill... a syphon isn't going to work here because the flow isn't continuous...

Comment: That will do it. No pitch to drain.

Comment: What should I do about it? Like the hvac is sitting on concrete slab of the crawlspace and I don't know how I could angle it down

Comment: I could put a brick or some sort of weight on it but that seems like it stress the pipe

Comment: Is the air handler sitting level or sloped away from drain line? It should’ve slightly sloped towards the drain

Comment: Level from what my 3 foot level is telling me

Comment: Try tilting the unit and putting a wedge under it that gives a pitch toward the drain hole. Also what is the size of the system and how big is the air return/returns. Too small a return air vent can create problems

Comment: Use a condensate pump for now until you figure this out. It's too hot outside to not have AC. Do you have a floor drain that's closer than your sump basin that you could use?